# Issue faced on installing MSSQL in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-18.04

On running

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
```

Shows

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.7)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.7) but 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but I also installed ODBC 17..

If anyone installed MSSQL and SQL Server command-line tools.

Kindly help.

Comment: Do do you have 17.3.0.0 or greater installed? If you run `apt-cache policy msodbcsql17` what is the Installed and Candidate versions?

Comment: Hai,
msodbcsql17:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 17.6.1.1-1

Comment: *"Installed: (**none**)"* Well that completely conflicts with your statement *"but I also installed ODBC 17"*, you clearly have not. Fix your unmet dependancies first... `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: Sorry, I followed the documentation steps of Microsoft,
done: sudo apt install -f,  

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 718 not upgraded.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't updated your system in some time if you have 718 not updated... I'd suggest getting your host up to date first.

Comment: Sir,  what I have to do next

Comment: From my prior comment: *"I'd suggest getting your host up to date first."*

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I tried to install **unixodbc-dev** before **ODBC 17**